# How can separate text block in Python application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning Python and writing an application that should show text blocks on the screen. I'm using the `tkinter` library.

Text in some blocks may not fit in one line, so I've decided to use `Text` widget because it has the option of wrapping text. And I've also used `Scrollbar` widget because text blocks may not fit the screen. So my code looks like this:

```
root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
t = Text(root, wrap=WORD)

def show_messages():
    for i in range (0, len(messages)):
         t.insert(END, messages[i] + '\n')

def show_windows():
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
    t.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

show_messages()
show_window()
```

And, after all, the messages should be separated with some kind of line, but I'm stuck on this. So, my question is: how can I separate my text blocks? Or maybe I'm going down the wrong path, and I should use `Listbox` widget instead of `Text`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you add text `----\n` as separation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by inserting a black frame using the window_create method of the Text widget:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
t = tk.Text(root, wrap="word")

messages = [
"""
#############################
#                           #
#       text block 1        #
#                           #
#############################
""",
"""
#############################
#                           #
#       text block 2        #
#                           #
#############################
"""
]

def show_messages():
    for i in range (0, len(messages)):
         t.insert("end", messages[i] + '\n')
         # add a black centered the text block
         f = tk.Frame(t, width=200, height=1, background="black")
         t.window_create("end", window=f)
         t.insert("end",'\n')

def show_windows():
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
    t.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

show_messages()
show_windows()
```